# What's difference between `run_in_executor ` and `run_in_threadpool` in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

In FastAPI, `run_in_executor` and `run_in_threadpool` both can let function running in other thread, and it **seems to have the same behavior**.

But what's **difference** between this ? And what's the best choice for using FastAPI?

Demo:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def index():
    result = await long_time_work()
    result = await long_time_work2()
    return {"message": result}


async def long_time_work():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 5)
    return True


async def long_time_work2():
    await run_in_threadpool(lambda: time.sleep(5))
    return True
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

`run_in_threadpool` is using `anyio.to_thread.run_sync` under the hood. This allows it to work with different async backends based on the environment (asyncio or trio).

Both of them are running sync methods in a thread pool but `run_in_executor` gives a lot more control to the user like selecting a different executor. This will allow you to run your sync methods in a specific thread pool separated from the default one, limiting the number of concurrent threads and even passing process executor instance to run them in separate processes.